# Format a decimal number in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal

I'm trying to format specific numbers up to 8 decimals by deleting unnecessary zeros.

My actual code is:

```
rtrim(sprintf("%.8f", $upto_eight_decimals), '0')
```

It actually prevents to format a number as 0.00012 into 1.2E-4 or 0.00012000

However, with numbers integer such as 1 it gets converted into 1. but this point is not my expected result (I know because of rtrim deleting all zeros).

**UPDATE:** `rtrim(rtrim(sprintf("%.8f", $upto_eight_decimals), '0'), '.')` it looks like working

Comment: try this:- `number_format((float)$upto_eight_decimals, 8, '.', '');`

Comment: Can you show what you actually mean by providing some sample inputs and required outputs please. Just so we can stop guessing at what problem you are actually trying to solve

Comment: I've added my new working code but I'm not sure it's a good method. I want to remove all unnecessary zeros, avoid float formatting (eg. 1.2E-4) and in case of integer (eg. 1) remove the eventual point (eg. 1.)

Comment: now test my answer. i update it, now its remove the unnecessary zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, Just use [number_format](http://php.net/number_format):

```
$upto_eight_decimals = "0.0001200";
$out = number_format((float)$upto_eight_decimals, 8, '.', '');

echo preg_replace("/\.?0*$/",'',$out);
or
echo $out + 0;
```

This function returns a string.

This will work for you, let me know is it work or not.

Comment: Result: 0.00012000. These zeros are not necessary.

Comment: now check it, now the unnecessary zeros remove from the output.

Comment: Cool! Looks like it's working. I'll save it into a note, however meantime I'll use my own code because I need it in 1 line only for multi purposal use on HTML pages. Thank you!